# select checkboxes with javascript based on html-5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is not working:

```
function autoScrub() {
  checkLength = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (var i=0; i < checkLength.length; i++) {
    if (checkLength[i].attr('data-z') === 1) {
      checkLength[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Each of my checkboxes has a `data-z` attribute of either 1 or 0.  I'd like to auto-check all of the checkboxes that have a `data-z` attribute of 1.  The code is breaking at `if (checkLength[i].attr('data-z') === 1) {` as apparently I cannot read the data-attribute this way.

Apart from this the rest of the code works fine.  I can use `checkLength[i].checked = true;` and it will check all of the checkboxes, I just can't reference its data-attribute correctly in an `if` statement and I'm not sure how to.

Any ideas?

## Update

I screwed around with two of the solutions below and finally came up with:

```
function autoScrub() {     
  $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("z") == 0) {      
        $(this).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');                                        
    } 
  }); 
}
```

and this worked.  Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just include the data attribute in your selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM element nodes don't have an `.attr()` method. I think you're looking for `.getAttribute()`.

```
if (checkLength[i].getAttribute('data-z') === "1") {
  checkLength[i].checked = true;
}
```

Also note that your attribute values will be strings, not numbers, so you'll either need to compare to strings as in my edit above, or else compare with `==`.

Since you tagged your post with the jQuery tag, I'll add that your code would look like this if you were to go that route:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function() {
  if ($(this).data("z") == 1)
    this.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: works perfectly - and thank you for the jQuery as well.  I like to compare between the two and I'm not as well versed in jQuery as i am vanilla.

Comment: I can post this as a new question if it's more appropriate, but prior to writing this, I had another function, `$('input[type="checkbox"]).change(function() {` that fired each time I clicked on a box - this is not firing anymore if I use this other function to auto-check the boxes.  Is there a way to make this run each time one of my boxes is autochecked?

Comment: @JohnWu well generally programmatic updates to `<input>` elements (etc) don't generate events. However you can do so yourself: `$(this).change();` will trigger the "change" event.

Answer (score 10):

in jQuery this is one line of code:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-z="1"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-z="1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" data-z="0" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" data-z="1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" data-z="1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" data-z="0" /><br />
```

#### EDIT

Just noticed a comment about firing the change event:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-z="1"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks very much for the `trigger` command.  I'm finding it only works to check the FIRST instance of `data-z="0"` that it finds though, ignoring all other instances of it.  I've tested on a sheet with five instances of `data-z="0"` and only the first instance got checked and triggered. (I changed it from `data-z="1"` to `data-z="0"` as that's what I actually wanted :))

Comment: @JohnWu Not sure why it's only working on one of them for you. I'd have to see your code. But, I have created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/nt0oxxq7/) so you can see it doesn't just do the first by default.

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"][data-checkbox_class="${$(this).attr('data-header_system_id')}"]').prop('checked', false);`   solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use pure html5 then use [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
//  el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03'; // set the DOB.

// 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === false

//  el.dataset.someDataAttr = 'mydata';
// 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === true


(function autoScrub() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  
  for (var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
    console.log(el[i].dataset.z)
    if (el[i].dataset.z === "1") {
      console.log(el[i]);
      el[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=check-1 data-id=111111 data-user=john data-date-of-birth=2jan2010 data-z=1 />
<input type=checkbox id=check-2 data-id=222222 data-user=tambo data-date-of-birth=3feb2011 data-z=2 />
<input type=checkbox id=check-3 data-id=333333 data-user=sandra data-date-of-birth data-z=3 />
<input type=checkbox id=check-4 data-id=444444 data-user=loic data-date-of-birth=4mar2012 data-z=4 />
```

**Note: Accessing the Data**

> The W3C HTML5 spec has a clear method for collecting data in
>   JavaScript.  Notice that we don’t need the “data-” in front of our
>   value like with getAttribute; we just call our value name directly.
>   This access method meets the spec, but like many HTML5 features, it
>   only works in HTML5 browsers.

Comment: This is really interesting.  i didn't know I could do this as well.  Let me play around with it.  Thanks for the time you put into this answer!  I really appreciate it.